# C++ OpenGL Segmentation fault (core dumped) runtime error

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, glsl, glfw

When I tried to run this I got a "Segmentation fault (core dumped) error and nothing ran:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include </home/rohan/Documents/opengl/common/loadShader.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main() {

    glewExperimental = true;
    if ( !glfwInit() )
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
    return -1;
    }
    
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make     MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,     GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    
    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
    
            // An array of 3 vectors which represents 3 vertices
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };
    
    // This will identify our vertex buffer
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data),         g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window.If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental=true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    
    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.glsl", "SimpleFragmentShader.glsl" );

    
    do{
        
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // 1st attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
    // unknown, size, type, normalized?, stride, array buffer offset
    0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    
    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);
    
    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0;        3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        
    }
    
    while(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
    
 }
```

vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
void main()
{
  color = vec3(1,0,0);
}
```

shader-loader:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::stringstream sstr;
        sstr << VertexShaderStream.rdbuf();
        VertexShaderCode = sstr.str();
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }else{
        printf("Impossible to open %s. Are you in the right directory ? Don't forget to read the FAQ !\n", vertex_file_path);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::stringstream sstr;
        sstr << FragmentShaderStream.rdbuf();
        FragmentShaderCode = sstr.str();
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    // Link the program
    printf("Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    }
    
    glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    
    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}
```

The code is supposed to make a red triangle appear.

Comment: Use your *debugger* to find out what line in the code is directly causing the segfault, and unwind from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call an OpenGL instruction, you need a valid and current [OpenGL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) and the OpenGL loader (in your case glew) must be in initialized. Therefore you cannot do the vertex specification before `glewInit`. Move all OpenGL commands after that:

```cpp
// [...]

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

// The earliest point for calling an OpenGL (gl*) instruction is here
// [...]
```

Note, `glewExperimental = True` is not further necessary (see [Initializing GLEW](https://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)).